# WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE is set but not going through the app setting

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I set the WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE in the application setting to New Zealand Standard Time

[image]

And in the console when I check the date

[image]

it has not been applied, I went to the resource explorer and checked the value in the config which is set to null.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server time is set to UTC. The application will be working correctly in NZ Time. To confirm this, please log the date time from within the app and check the logs to confirm the date is correct.

**Kia Kaha** Milad,

Mike Smith